# Issue with angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router, angular-meteor

I'm trying to learn AngularJS and Meteor.
I'm working on c9.io.
I'm trying to realize a simple menu.
This is my folders structure:
[image]

And this is the code:
**index.html**

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <title>Navigazione</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="content">
    <page></page>
  </div>
</body>
```

**main.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';

import page from '../imports/ui/page/page';

angular.module('content', [
  angularMeteor,
  page.name
]);
```

**menu.html**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in menuCtrl.items">
    <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">{{item.text}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**menu.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';

import template from './menu.html';

const name = 'menu';

class MenuCtrl {
  constructor() {
    this.items = [{
      text: 'Home',
      link: 'home'
    }, 
    {
      text: 'Lights',
      link: 'lights'
    }, 
    {
      text: 'Temperatures',
      link: 'temperatures'
    }];
  }
}

export default angular
  .module(name, [
    angularMeteor
  ])
  .component(name, {
    templateUrl: template,
    controllerAs: 'menuCtrl',
    controller: MenuCtrl
  })
```

**page.html**

```
<header>
  <h1>Page</h1>
</header>

<menu></menu>

<div ui-view></div>
```

**page.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

import template from './page.html';
import menu from '../../components/menu/menu';
import home from '../pages/home/home';
import lights from '../pages/lights/lights';
import temperatures from '../pages/temperatures/temperatures';

const name = 'page';

export default angular.module(name, [
  angularMeteor,
  uiRouter,
  menu.name,
  home.name,
  lights.name,
  temperatures.name
])
  .component(name, {
    templateUrl: template,
    controllerAs: name
  })
  .config(config);

function config($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  'ngInject';
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
}
```

**lights.html**

```
<header>
  <h1>Lights</h1>
</header>

<div>{{lgt.luci}}</div>
```

**lights.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

import template from './lights.html';

const name = 'lights';

class LightsCtrl {
  constructor() {
    this.luci = 'Hello';
  }
}

export default angular
  .module(name, [
    angularMeteor,
    uiRouter
  ])
  .component(name, {
    templateUrl: template,
    controller: LightsCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'lgt'
  })
  .config(config);

function config($stateProvider) {
  'ngInject';
  $stateProvider
    .state(name, {
      url: '/'+name,
      templateUrl: template,
      controllerAs: 'lgt',
      controller: LightsCtrl
    });
}
```

**home.html**

```
<header>
  <h1>Home</h1>
</header>
```

**home.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

import template from './home.html';

class HomeCtrl {}

const name = 'home';

// create a module
export default angular.module(name, [
  angularMeteor,
  uiRouter
]).component(name, {
  template,
  controllerAs: name,
  controller: HomeCtrl
})
  .config(config);

function config($stateProvider) {
  'ngInject';
  $stateProvider
    .state(name, {
      url: '/'+name,
      templateUrl: template
    });
}
```

**temperatures.html**

```
<header>
  <h1>Home</h1>
</header>
```

**temperatures.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

import template from './home.html';

class TemperaturesCtrl {}

const name = 'temperatures';

// create a module
export default angular.module(name, [
  angularMeteor,
  uiRouter
]).component(name, {
  template,
  controllerAs: name,
  controller: TemperaturesCtrl
})
  .config(config);

function config($stateProvider) {
  'ngInject';
  $stateProvider
    .state(name, {
      url: '/'+name,
      templateUrl: template
    });
}
```

this is the final result:
[image]

My problem concerns the definition of the controller in the **lights.js** page.
Reading the AngularJS documentation I was sure that in a component you have to define the controller. Then if you declare a controller in wich you declare a variable, you can get it in the template (see the menu.js component).
The problem is that it is not so simple. I can find my variable that says "Hello" only if I declare the controller and the controller as in the state definition. Where am I wrong?

Here you can find the project: [GitHub](https://github.com/stecape/c9-Meteor)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: So,from where u want to access the controller `LightsCtrl `?

Comment: from the component.